# Use of the and keyword in F# in discriminated unions

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, discriminated-union

I was faced today with the following DUs declarations:

```
type Grammar = Definition list

and  Definition = Def of string * Expression

and  Range =
     | Char  of char
     | Range of char * char
```

Why would one use the keyword `and` instead of `type`, here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `and` is needed for the definitions of `Grammar` and `Definition` to compile correctly.  The `Grammar` type is listed first but depends on the type `Definition` which is defined later.  In order to compile properly it must be linked with `and` which tells the F# compiler the type definitions are dependent / related.

There is no reason for `Range` to be declared in such a way and should be declared with `type`

Comment: Also, `Grammar` could be placed after the declaration of `Definition` and then they'd be no reason to use `and` on any of them.

Answer (score 16):

It's used to create mutually related types. Usually in F#, you need to forward declare each type before you use it - but this isn't always possible, for example when you need to introduce a cyclic dependency on two or more types.

In your example, if you defined `Definition` with `type` rather than `and`, you wouldn't be able to compile the definition of `Grammar`, unless you switched the order in which they're defined.

The code example you've posted isn't exactly a good one, because the mutual relation isn't necessary in it - you can change the order. (Unless there were some more types defined further down which depended on the above).