# Modeling complex hierarchies in F#

Tags: f#

I'm fairly new to F#, and I want to model things in the real world that have fairly complex "has-a" relationships. At the top of the hierarchy are four types, A - D, with these relationships:

```
A
|
+--A
|
+--B
|  |
|  +--B
|  |
|  +--D
|     |
|     +--D
|
+--C
|  |
:  +--D
|     |
|     +--D
:
```

So  type B can have a "parent" of either A or B, and type D can have a parent of B, C or D.

I want to use discriminated unions to constrain the parent of each type, so they can't be assigned to invalid parents, e.g:

```
type B_Parent = A | B
type D_Parent = B | C | D
```

Then I want to use records to model each type, where one field is the parent, e.g:

```
type A = { parent:A_Parent; ... }
type B = { parent:B_Parent; ... }
type C = { parent:C_Parent; ... }
type D = { parent:D_Parent; ... }
```

C_Parent isn't a problem because its parent type A is declared beforehand. And I have used 'A option' for A_Parent. But I haven't been able to work out how to define B_Parent and D_Parent, because of their nested dependency on themselves, and on other types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, one very important thing: when you write

```
type B_Parent = A | B
```

you are **not** declaring that `B_Parent` is a DU joining the two previously-defined types `A` and `B`. There is no syntax for that.

What the line above is actually doing is defining two empty subtypes of `B_Parent`, which have nothing to do with the original `A` and `B`. It is equivalent to:

```
type B_Parent = B_Parent.A | B_Parent.B
```

In order to re-use existing types inside a DU, you *need* to give a name to the case - effectively wrapping them in another type. So the proper declaration can be something like:

```
type B_Parent = P_a of A | P_b of B
```

With that aside - as Anton said, the keyword for defining mutually referential types is `and`. That said, it is best to keep such mutual references as small and tight as possible. So we could do something like this:

```
type A = { parent:A_Parent; ... }
    and A_Parent = P_a of A
                 | None

type B = { parent:B_Parent; ... }
    and B_Parent = P_a of A 
                 | P_b of B

type C = { parent:C_Parent; ... }
    and C_Parent = P_a of A

type D = { parent:D_Parent; ... }
    and D_Parent = P_b of B 
                 | P_c of C 
                 | P_d of D
```

We could have used just `A option` for `A_Parent`, and just `A` for `C_Parent`, but I think that keeping the case names consistent will probably make things more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have implemented it and it works fine. But I have another problem.

Comment: Sometimes I have to modify a record, or move it to a different parent - which is easy to do. But because F# records are immutable, this creates a new record, but I'm still left with the original one in memory. And I don't know how to get rid of that?

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of it? Let the garbage collector clean it up when it's no longer used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `and` keyword to define types that are mutually related, for example:

```
type B_Parent = A | B
and D_Parent = B | C | D
and A_Parent = A
and C_Parent = B
and A = { parent:A_Parent }
and B = { parent:B_Parent }
and C = { parent:C_Parent }
and D = { parent:D_Parent }
```

See also this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154418/use-of-the-and-keyword-in-f-in-discriminated-unions). The `and` keyword is also helpful when defining [mutually recursive functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/recursive-functions-the-rec-keyword-[fsharp]).